# Folder level script referencing document level script

Tags: javascript, acrobat

I have the following javascript code that works at the document level in Adobe Acrobat 10 when the document is opened (enveloped in this.addScript):

```
var nNumFields = this.numFields; 
var cFieldName; 
var oField; 
for(i = 0; i < nNumFields; i++) 
{
    cFieldName = this.getNthFieldName(i);
    oField = this.getField(cFieldName);
    oField.textFont = \"PTSans\";
}
```

I want to avoid going through multiple documents and adding this script to all of them. Is there a way to adapt this code to the folder level so it works for all acrobat opened documents?? If so what would it be?

Or is there a way to add this script for a list of documents quickly (programmatically) instead of manually?? (manually as in by opening the document, inserting the script into the debugger, running it, then saving the document, then repeating for every document)

Comment: You can use an Acrobat Action to run the script over a folder full of PDF files. When creating the action, select Execute JavaScript as the action to run then paste your code into the JavaScript window.

Comment: How does one create an action in Acrobat 10 (not Pro)?

Comment: Acrobat 10 ended support in 2015. Also, only the pro versions of Acrobat DC supports Actions.